# Missing random files

Tags: windows-xp

Lately random files have been missing from my Windows XP computer. These are read-only files that definitely haven't been modified or removed by me (a boost header file and an SDK library file).

I ran a manual scan of the anti virus software (which is supposed to run anyway). It found no result, except of a "potential security threat" inside a zip file.

I also ran chkdsk /f which found no results. (The system crashes frequently when it awakes from hibernation so I suspected it was a disk error.)

I can try and restore the files, but I want to know what caused the problem. What do you think has happened, and what can I do to find or fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

A disk error does not normally cause inoffensive files to disappear, neither do viruses.

However, Windows is entirely capable of doing weird things in weird situations, so I would rather concentrate on the crashes you're getting.

In your case, the only sleep problem counsel I can give is
to look in your BIOS for the suspend ACPI options and try to switch modes among "S1 and S3", "S1", "S3" etc.
If this doesn't help it should be returned to the previous value.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it the next time I reboot the computer.

Comment: No such setting in BIOS. But note that I use hibernation, not suspension or sleep. It looks to me like it's all in the OS level, not related to BIOS.

Comment: You may verify Windows by entering "sfc /scannow" in administrator cmd. You can also run more antivirus checks, recommended are MBAM, Avast and Spybot S&D.